# Write image text to a new text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

I am using tesseract for OCR. I am on ubuntu 18.04.

I have this program which extracts the texts from an image and print it. I want that program to create a new text file and paste the extracted content on to the new text file, but I am only able to do these

- copy the content to clipboard
- open new texteditor(geditor) file
  I don't know how to paste the copied content

Here is my program which extracts the text from image

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string 
from PIL import Image
print image_to_string(Image.open('sample.jpg'))
```

Here is the program which copies the text to clipboard,

```
import os
def addToClipBoard(text):
    command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
    os.system(command)
```

This program will open the geditor and create  a new text file

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['gedit', 'file.txt'])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not open a new file (in your program) and write the extracted text into it?

Comment: Do you have to use the clipboard or you just want the text in a text file?

Comment: @MohitMotwani I just want the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the text, then open a text file and write to it:

```
from pytesseract import image_to_string 
from PIL import Image
text =  image_to_string(Image.open('sample.jpg'))

with open('file.txt', mode = 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: It keeps on overwriting the file, is there any way  to create a new "file.txt" with different name, say "file1.txt" and when I run it again "file2.txt"

Comment: You can write a for loop and add in numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Just as I proposed in the comment, create a new file and write the extracted text into it:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(image_to_string(Image.open('sample.jpg')))
```